# Search on splunk not working with the API

Tags: curl, splunk-cloud

I'm trying to catch the response of a search in the logs using the API of the staging version of Splunk in my compagny. 
To connect to the API, I'm using a token. My command is :

```
curl -k https://compagnyInstance.splunkcloud.com:8089/services/search/jobs --header 'Authorization: Bearer Token' -d search "search index="proxy" "
```

And the response is :

> curl: (28) Failed to connect to compagnyInstance.splunkcloud.com port 8089 after 21060 ms:
> Couldn't connect to server
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer
> curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
> curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

The big problem is that for one of my colleagues, this same command is working perfectly. 
Even when I just want to connect without anything like

```
curl -k https://compagnyInstance.splunkcloud.com:8089
```

I get this:

> curl: (28) Failed to connect to compagnyInstance.splunkcloud.com port 8089 after 21063 ms: Couldn't connect to server

I am not in the firewall of my company by the way

```
curl -k https://compagnyInstance.splunkcloud.com:8089/services/search/jobs --header 'Authorization: Bearer Token' -d search "search index="proxy" "
```

And I want to have a response to the research

Comment: Some companies require users be inside the company firewall/VPN to access Splunk Cloud.

Comment: You have mismatched quote marks - `search "search index="proxy" "` should *probably be* `search 'search index="proxy" '` (or just remove the quote marks around `proxy` like this: `search "search index=proxy "`)